# Could imported DLL functions be calling the wrong function versions if the exe statically links to a different msvcr?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, msvcrt

I have a strange issue that I am trying to work out for someone. I don't have any access to the code. There is a program that loads a DLL and has somewhat of a plugin framework. They provide virtually no documentation beyond how to import functions from the DLL and what calling convention to use for exports.

This person's plugin imports functions from a DLL (let's assume they used the proper calling conventions and imported properly). It periodically runs into access violations (usually access violation write/read from 0x0000000). Sometimes, it crashes the program and Event Viewer shows exception code 0xc0000005 (another access violation) with faulting module SHLWAPI.dll.

Using depends, I have determined that the program is statically linked to msvcr. I found that the plugin DLL dynamically links to msvcr120.dll.

Yes, I am aware that this is just asking for trouble and the access violations are no surprise, but unfortunately, I have to deal with someone else's problem.

Anyway, my question is this:
Let's say  is imported from this DLL and inside  is a call to a function  that is provided by msvcr120. When the program calls the imported , is it possible that it is calling  from the msvcr it is statically linked to rather than from msvcr120?

I realize that it probably depends on the main program's plugin framework, but general feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If a DLL statically links against the CRT, each and every CRT function call from that DLL calls the statically linked function. The object code has the function calls baked in. It never goes through an import table redirection. Your real issue is, that someone is passing a `nullptr`, that SHLWAPI is trying to dereference. Break into the debugger, and the callstack takes you right to the bug.

Comment: @IInspectable The DLL DYNAMICALLY links to msvcr120. The question was since the EXE is statically linked to a different msvcr, could it be calling that msvcr's functions rather than msvcr120? As for debugging, unfortunately, the program has some stupid protection. Trying to use a debugger on it causes it to exit with a warning not to use a debugger.

Comment: The EXE doesn't export any imports from the statically linked CRT. The DLL will always call the dynamically linked version in that case. If the application doesn't want to be debugged, attach a capable debugger, set a function breakpoint for [IsDebuggerPresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx) and have it always return 0. In WinDbg syntax: `bp kernel32!IsDebuggerPresent "g @$ra; r eax = 0; g"`.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, thanks for clarifying. As for the debugger, merely attaching causes it to close. I've tried WinDbg and OllyDbg.

Comment: Have you tried running the application from the debugger, though, while disabling the call to `IsDebuggerPresent` as outlined in my previous comment?

Comment: Just-in-time debugging (attaching a debugger in response to the crash) should still work, I'd have expected.

Comment: @IInspectable When running the app from the debugger, I get "A debugger has been found in your system. Please, unload it from memory and restart your program." Just in time debugging does not work either. Very annoying. Ok, now this is personal, I must break open this program!!!

Comment: @IInspectable Nevermind! I managed to pause it and do as you said just before it exited. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul you can also launch the process from WinDbg (File->Open Executable), and it will allow you to set the breakpoints before the program is active.

Comment: @theB That would be easier than trying to hit pause really fast. However, when I do that, the process starts. Is there any option I need to change?

Comment: @Paul - Without knowing the specifics of their scheme I'd just be guessing. Symantec has [a good article](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference) on anti-debugger techniques, and workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are known issues when using multiple copies of the CRT in one program, even when they all use the same version of the CRT (see [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx)).  If the CRTs are different versions, there are lots of other problems due to different size or layout of internal structures.

Since the program you use statically links with the CRT, it can not reliably be plugged in to.  The anti-debugger code is just plain silly; there are several ways around it.  If you paid for it send it back and demand a refund.

Comment: It's not really *that* much of a problem if you follow the rules.  (Don't allocate memory in one module and free it in another, don't try to pass anything but POD between modules, remember that file descriptors are per-module, and so on.)  But it does require great care and is certainly not for the faint of heart. :-)

Comment: Nice link! Agreed, anti-debugger code is stupid. I managed to override it in ollydbg with the help of IInspectable's advice. It's not even licensed (free software) so no idea why they thought that was a smart idea.